# Mutating version of tap -- or a way to pipe expressions?

Tags: ruby

`tap` yields `self` to the block passed to it, and returns `self` unaltered.  I often find myself wishing there was a version of `tap` which returned the return value of the block, rather than `self`.  For example:

```
[1,2].inject(:+).tap {|x| x * 3} #=> returns 3, but I want 9
```

Is there any builtin method that will accomplish this?

The typical solution -- create a temporarily local var to store the output of `[1,2].inject(:+)`, and multiply that by 3 -- seems kludgy.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "returns `self` unaltered". For example, `{ a: 1 }.tap { |h| h[:a]=2 } #=> {:a=>2} `. You could write `[3].tap { |a| a.replace [9] } #=> [9]`, but that only works because arrays are mutable. You clearly can't do that with immutable objects like `Fixnums`.

Comment: I should have said "returns self".  In contrast to what I want: "returns what the block returns"

Comment: You could, of course, do that by wrapping it in a method and short-circuiting the return: `def doit(arr); arr.inject(:+).tap {|x| return x * 3}; end`. Then `doit [1,2] #=> 9`.

Comment: That defeats the point, as my aim is syntactic compactness to express a common idea: pipelining values.  I want the unix `|`.  Monkeypatching seems the only way to do it.

Comment: It was just an observation, not a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an older question, but you can now use [`yield_self`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in method for that, but you can add [`Kernel#ergo`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Kernel%3Aergo) from [Ruby Facets](http://rubyworks.github.io/facets/):

```
"a".ergo.upcase #=> "A"
nil.ergo.foobar #=> nil

"a".ergo { |o| o.upcase } #=> "A"
nil.ergo { |o| o.foobar } #=> nil
```

> This is like #tap, but #tap yields self and returns self, where as #ergo yields self but returns the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this yourself.

```
class Object
  def my_tap
    return yield self if block_given?
    self
  end
end

[1,2].inject(:+).my_tap {|x| x * 3}
=> 9
```

Comment: yeah, i know,  i wanted to avoid monkeypatching Object though.

Comment: Yeah but money patching isn't always evil. I like @Mori 's answer though

Comment: I agree, it's probably fine in this case with a unique name.  i find it odd that ruby doesn't support such a basic concept natively though...

Comment: Interesting, Steve! I don't the name should contain "tap", though, because it has nothing to do with `tap` (`chain`, perhaps?). It could of course be a `Refinement` of `Object`.

Comment: This is really interesting. If we had this method would we need `tap`?  I can't think of a case where the method would be used without a block. Can you? ([Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) appears to require a block.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland agree that "my_tap" is a misnomer, I think I was prompted by the phrasing of the question "...(alternate) version of tap...".  As to what it should do if no block present... return self, return nil, raise error... maybe raising an error would be the most sensible?

Comment: Steve, my vote goes to raising an exception if no block is present (ala `tap`). I had the same reaction as @Jonah: why isn't it  a built-in now? Maybe you're on to something.