# Access `self` of an object through the parameters

Tags: ruby

Let's say I want to access an element of an array at a random index this way:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].at(rand(4))
```

Is there a way to pass the size of the array like the following?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].at(rand(le_object.self.size))
```

Why would I do that?--A great man once said:
Science isn't about why, it is about why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not recommended, but [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) would somehow work:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].instance_eval { at(rand(size)) }
```

And you can also [`break`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) out of [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].tap { |a| break a.at(rand(a.size)) }
```

There's an open [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6721) to add a method that yields `self` and returns the block's result. If that makes it into Ruby, you could write:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].insert_method_name_here { |a| a.at(rand(a.size)) }
```

Comment: Until the feature request completes, [`#ergo`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Kernel%3Aergo) from [Ruby Facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets) can do it: `require 'facets'; [1, 2, 3, 4].ergo {|ary| ary.at(rand(ary.size)) }`

Comment: @cbliard do you have any idea why `#ergo` calls `instance_eval` when there's more than one block argument?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: not one to be used, though :)

Comment: @Stefan: or obfuscation contest :)

Comment: @Stefan I guess it's when block has no arguments: `[1, 2, 3, 4].ergo { at(rand(size)) }`. This use case is not documented though.

Comment: See also SteveTurczyn's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301057/mutating-version-of-tap-or-a-way-to-pipe-expressions/34301320#comment56355485_34301320).

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that. Receiver of a method (that array) is not accessible by some special name at the call site. Your best bet is assigning a name to that object.

```
ary = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ary.at(rand(ary.size))
```

Of course, if all you need is a random element, then `.sample` should be used. Which does not require evaluation of any arguments at the call site and its `self` is the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instance_eval` to execute ruby code with the binding of the array variable

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].instance_eval { at(rand(size)) }
```

Assuming you are interested in a random element as `Array#at` returns an element at given index, you can use `Array#sample` to pick a random element from an array.

```
[1,2,3,4].sample
#=> 3
```

If you do not want to use `instance_eval` (or any form of `eval`), then, you can add a method to `Array` class by monkey patching - generally speaking, I am not sure whether it's a wise idea to monkey patch though

```
class Array
  def random_index
    rand(size)
  end
end

["a","b","c","d"].random_index
#=> 2
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for the tip - updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar with lambda:

```
getrand = ->(x) { x[rand(x.count)] }
getrand.call [1,2,3]
# => 2
```

Comment: Or totally anonymous: `->x { x.at(rand(x.size)) }.call [1, 2, 3, 4]`