# Refer to receiver object in a method argument?

Tags: ruby

Consider, for example, an array cross product with itself:

```
[1,2,3].product([1,2,3])
#=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

What I'd like to write is something like:

```
[1,2,3].product(receiver)
```

`self` won't work here, and creating a temp variable like `temp = [1,2,3]`  to do `temp.product(temp)` is a kludge.

Is there a good built in way to accomplish this?

**NOTE:** I'm not looking for a solution to the Array example given, but for a solution to the general problem of referring to the receiver object.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34338713/477037

Comment: I think I finally understand what you are asking.  You generated an array but it is not assigned to any variable yet.  Without assigning it to a variable, you want to know how you can get the product of the array with itself.  I think this is a better way to explain it; you never defined what `receiver` is and just left us to guess.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, Yes, and thank you.  Your explanation is clear and succinct.

Comment: @Stefan, Thanks.  That is indeed the same question I'm asking.

Comment: ```[1,2,3].instance_eval { product self }```

Comment: The `instance eval` approach illustrated with a runnable code snippet: http://rubysandbox.com/#/snippet/56753647c55987000c000003

Answer (score 1):

You could extend Array:

```
class Array
  def selfproduct
    self.product(self)
  end
end
p [1,2].selfproduct()   #-> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
p [1,2,3].selfproduct() #->[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: The array was just a concrete example.  I'd like a general solution to the problem of refering to the object receiving the method.

Comment: OK, then your question seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338713/access-self-of-an-object-through-the-parameters

Comment: Agreed.  And that question was asked just yesterday, wow.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, I did search, and it didn't come up, because the language we were using to describe the question is different.